# Is it possible to insert data from one server to another in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

My requirement.

I want to insert all the records on my local database to web server database automatically at given time. like

```
insert into mywebservername.databasename.dbo.mytable select * from my localtable
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: You need to make sure you have linked servers for just the insert. If you want to insert data then you'll have to be doing that on a table by table basis. If you want to copy the whole database then a backup and restore would be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can add the target server as a Linked Server in your server and then you can insert. Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188279(v=sql.105).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782(v=sql.105).aspx)